# Plotting of Boxplot for numerical variables only

Tags: r

I want to draw a boxplot side by side for 3 numerical variables. There is no categorical variables in the dataset. Is there any way to do this? Also the labels for the variables, I want to highlight in x-axis like `var1`, `var2`, `var3`.

The dataset has 0 categorical variables and has only 4 numerical variables?

The dataset is

```
   var1 var2      var3
1     1    3   918.280
2     3    9  8891.513
3     5   15 22479.261
4     2    4  2961.131
5     7   14 19650.198
6     1    2   377.750
7     1    5  2671.930
8     3    3   966.150
9     2    6  3765.810
10    4    8  7467.110
```

Comment: @ SibaMishra: you should click on tick to accept the best answer and upvote for others which helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ggplot2 can also be used:

```
ddf = structure(list(var1 = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L
), var2 = c(3L, 9L, 15L, 4L, 14L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 8L), var3 = c(918.28, 
8891.513, 22479.261, 2961.131, 19650.198, 377.75, 2671.93, 966.15, 
3765.81, 7467.11), id = 1:10), .Names = c("var1", "var2", "var3", 
"id"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

ddf
   var1 var2      var3 id
1     1    3   918.280  1
2     3    9  8891.513  2
3     5   15 22479.261  3
4     2    4  2961.131  4
5     7   14 19650.198  5
6     1    2   377.750  6
7     1    5  2671.930  7
8     3    3   966.150  8
9     2    6  3765.810  9
10    4    8  7467.110 10

ddm = melt(ddf, id='id')
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(ddm)+geom_boxplot(aes(x=variable, y=log(value)))
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly i wanted the ggplot. So Answer from #Barranka is appreciated.. Could u please explain why L is used with each variables of the data vector. Adding one more new variable in the same ggplot can be done or not? Currently after adding a new numerical variable, i am facing the problem "Error: unexpected string constant in:"var3". The generated ggplot is more huge. Is there any solution to reduce the sizes of boxs.. Kindly do reply. Kindly explain all the terminologies used above, as i am new in R.. Also the answer from # thelatemail is appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Thank You Man. Real nice blog

Comment: 1 question.. How to change the label of x and y axis of the ggplot

Comment: Use +labs function of ggplot2 to change x and y axis labels.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your "numerical variables" are vectors, you can create a data frame that holds all three of them and create the boxplot:

```
var1 <- c(1, 3, 5, 2, 7, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4)
var2 <- c(3, 9, 15, 4, 14, 2, 5, 3, 6, 8)
var3 <- c(918.28, 8891.513, 22479.261, 2961.131, 19650.198, 377.75, 2671.93, 966.15, 3765.81, 7467.11)

df <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3)
boxplot(df)
```

However, the scale is a problem, so one alternative may be to combine the three individual box plots in a single figure:

```
opar <- par(no.readonly = T) # Save the original graphical settings
par(mfrow = c(1,3)) # This will create a plot "matrix" with one row and three columns
boxplot(var1, main='var1')
boxplot(var2, main='var2')
boxplot(var3, main='var3')
par(opar) # Restore the original graphical settings
```

or, as suggested by [thelatemail in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25440244/plotting-of-boxplot-for-numerical-variables-only/25440459?noredirect=1#comment39691905_25440459), change the `y` axis to log-scale:

```
boxplot(df, log='y')
```

Comment: Or log the y-axis: `boxplot(df,log="y")`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be `boxplot(var1, var2, var3)`

Comment: OP specifically requested x-axis variable names to match the description.